# Cipher Code Wont Work

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I started learning c++ recently and I have been trying to create solutions to challenge myself, one of these challenges was a cipher that encrypts text and eventually saves it to a text file. The code I am currently using will not compile because it wont recognize the replace statement, this is my code so far.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
// declare all variables
std::string text;
std::string s;
std::string uncipheredText;

//Introducing the program
std::cout << "Welcome to Cipher." << std::endl;

//Asks the user to input the text they want to encrypt and saves it to the unciphered text variable.
std::cout << "Enter the text you want to cipher" << std::endl;
std::cin >> s;

//replaces all characters in the variable "s"
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'Q', 'M');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'E', 'B');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'T', 'C');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'U', 'Z');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'O', 'S');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'L', 'F');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'J', 'H');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'G', 'K');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'D', 'P');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'A', 'I');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'X', 'Y');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'V', 'R');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'N', 'W');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), ' ', '#');


s = text;

std::cout << "Encrypted Text: " << text << std::endl;

//replaces all characters in the variable "s"
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'Q', 'M');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'E', 'B');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'T', 'C');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'U', 'Z');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'O', 'S');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'L', 'F');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'J', 'H');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'G', 'K');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'D', 'P');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'A', 'I');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'X', 'Y');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'V', 'R');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'N', 'W');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), ' ', '#');

s = uncipheredText;

std::cout << "Decrypted Text: " << uncipheredText << std::endl;

/*
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("dump.txt");
myfile << text;
myfile.close();
*/

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation of [`std::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace)? If you did, you would know, that it is defined in `<algorithm>`. Did you include it?

Comment: s = text    Isn't "text" just an empty string at this point?

Comment: You're writing assignments the wrong way around.

Comment: Your encryption is the same as your decryption

Comment: Reminder:  characters in C++ are *case sensitive*, a.k.a 'Q' != 'q'.  See also 'toupper`, `tolower` and `transform`.

Comment: Looks like you could simplify the code by using a table or `std::map` (associative container).  Iterate through the container, replacing the original character with the encrypted character.  This will allow easy decryption too, as you replace the encrypted character with the original character.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by @Algirdas Preidžius, you need to include algorithm library. Also, you duplicated this code:

```
//replaces all characters in the variable "s"
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'Q', 'M');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'E', 'B');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'T', 'C');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'U', 'Z');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'O', 'S');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'L', 'F');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'J', 'H');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'G', 'K');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'D', 'P');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'A', 'I');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'X', 'Y');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'V', 'R');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'N', 'W');
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), ' ', '#');
```